# SQL Left join Query Issue

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I have the following tables

```
Users
ID Name
1  John Smith
2  James Jones
3  Peter Brown

Purchases
USERID   NAME
1        Apple
1        Pear
1        Banana
2        Apple
2        Pear
3        Apple
```

How can i have a sql query that returns users that brought (apple & pear & banana)

So in the above tables it would return only 'John Smith'

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  A flexible way to solve this is using `group by` and `having`:

```
select userid
from purchases
where name in ('apple', 'pear', 'banana')
group by userid
having count(*) = 3;
```

To get the name, you would join in the `Users` table.

If, unlike in your sample data, duplicates are allowed in the table, then use `count(distinct name) = 3` in the `having` clause.

Comment: Yes, but if a person made multiple purchases, then the count would provide false matches.  For example, if user `2` bought another `Pear` he would have a count of 3, even though he only bought two of the items.  Thus, you'd want to have a `distinct` in there some place, or another `select * from purchases group by userid, name`

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` both tables and `COUNT` products:

```
SELECT u.Name
FROM Purchases p
JOIN Users u
  ON p.UserID = u.ID
WHERE p.Name IN ('Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana')
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.Name) = 3;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faa5e/5/0)**</kbd>

There is possibility that user has bought 2 apples and one banana so you should count distinct product names.

If you are using `Postgresql/SQL Server/Oracle` you need to wrap `Name` with aggregation function:

```
SELECT MAX(u.Name) AS Name
FROM Purchases p
JOIN Users u
  ON p.UserID = u.ID
WHERE p.Name IN ('Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana')
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.Name) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/71a22/8)

```
SELECT users.name, purchased.items
FROM users
INNER JOIN (
  select userid as id, array_agg(distinct name) items
  from purchases
  group by userid
  having array_length(array_agg(distinct name),1)=3
) purchased USING(id);
```

---

This does not work if you are only looking for those specific items.  If there are other items that could be purchased and you are only looking for users that purchased those specific items, you would have to do something similar to what Gordon, with a correction for the number of times an item was purchased.